# How to draw scalable rectangles Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails to create a website, and I am looking for a way (preferably most conventional one) to create white rectangles that will cover the back of texts only (To make it easier to read).

I have good previous knowledge of java, C and python like languages however I am completely unfamiliar with RoR, HTML, CSS.

I simply finished the following blog tutorial and just added a background.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
Therefore I don't have any relevant code to share, its just the basic stuff.

I would also appreciate further tips on how to have better control over the figures I will draw (how to make corners slightly rounded, how to make the rectangle size slightly larger than the text size etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you want to draw a poster as if using Adobe Illustrator or something like that.

For WEB design, you shouldn't reason like this. Think of your webpages mainly as a collection of containers that squeeze and adapt to your content.

1. create white rectangles that will cover the back of texts

This is just going to be the background of your containers. But if you really want something that is only covering the letters, you could try something like

HTML :

```
<span class="white-shadow">Your text</span>
```

CSS

```
.white-shadow{
  background: white;
}
```

2. make corners slightly rounded

It's a CSS property called

```
.your_class{
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0; // Round corners of 2px radius for top left/right corners
}
```

3. make the rectangle size slightly larger than the text size

You actually want to add some padding to your containers

```
.container{
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

If you don't understand any of this, I strongly recommend you to follow a HTML/CSS tutorial.

Comment: Also, if you're new to the WEB, then starting with Server programming feels weird. You should have focused on HTML/CSS/JS first, before trying to understand how WEB servers serve content. But it's just my opinion. It feels like you just learned multiplication before addition.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was looking for, quite to the point thank you! And server programming feels quite weird indeed. I kind of have a sense of what is going on, but it feels like there are too many keywords and syntax conventions. Anyway, I will consider taking few tutorials as you suggested, especially if I feel lost as I proceed. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah, RoR is a lot about convention and stuff happening under the hood. I still remember how weird it was for me when I first saw a controller actions like this : `def show { #nothing } end` and I had no idea what kind of black magic was still making this work xD

Answer (score 1):

I see I'm a few minutes late to this party, but just in case this helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SO30947882 Test</title>
<style>
body { /* The entire page's <body> element */
  background-color: gray;
}

* { /* Every element */
  color: black;
}

.my-text { /* Elements with this class property */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Hard to read this.</p>
<p class="my-text">Easier to read this, in a block.</p>
<p>
  <label>Dark text.</label> <label class="my-text">Better text, inline.</label><br/>
  <label>M<span class="my-text">ixe</span>d T<span class="my-text">ex</span>t.</label>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is some really fundamental CSS style definition stuff. CSS selectors (like `body` and `.my-text` here) are incredibly powerful, since they naturally combine.

Happy styling.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it was all really helpful :) Have a nice day.

Comment: Cheers. BTW nowadays I find Mozilla's reference sites to be my favorite:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web